# How to create UDIM image tile in python?

Tags: python, uv

I want to have UDIM image tiles only where a UV island is available in the space.

like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean UDIM tiles ? Could you elaborate a bit more, please ? This question looks like it didn't take a lot of effort to make.

Comment: Yes, UDIM tiles based on UV island position

Comment: I recommend adding a brief description of what you have and what you want to achieve. In the current state, your question is unclear, and as a reader one does not know what exactly it is about and what should be achieved.

Comment: Can you create a UDIM image tile where there are UV islands of a mesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not perfect, you need to add properties to adjust the parameters of the tiles (such as resolution, bit rate, and so on).

So, first you need to create a texture, with the Tile checkbox on, and then the 'Missed Tile Add' panel will appear, after which you can create tiles by clicking on the buttons. The script is guided by the position of vertexes of your juwi and adds missing tiles by them.

Here you could avoid using the operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT'), but the operation of adding tiles is not frequent and you can do it that way.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

from bpy.props import (
    FloatVectorProperty,
    FloatProperty,
    StringProperty,
    BoolProperty,
    EnumProperty,
    IntProperty,
    )

def get_data_from_collection(collection, attribute, size, dtype=np.float32):
    data = np.zeros(np.prod(size), dtype=dtype)
    collection.foreach_get(attribute, data)
    return data.reshape(size)


def create_unique_uv_coords():
    '''UV vertext to unique uv vertex, and convert float to int'''    
    uv_coords_for_udim = set()
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        if obj.type != 'MESH':
            continue
        active_uv = obj.data.uv_layers.active
        if active_uv:
            # Get UV coordinates
            uv = np.array( get_data_from_collection(active_uv.data, 'uv', (len(active_uv.data), 2)) )
            
            # Convert float to int
            uv_coords_floor = np.floor(uv).astype(int)
            
            # Unique coordinates
            unique_udim_coords = np.unique(uv_coords_floor, axis=0)
            
            # Numpy arrays to tuple
            to_list = unique_udim_coords.tolist()
            tpl = tuple(tuple((i[0]+1, i[1])) for i in to_list)
            
            # Unique coordinates
            uv_coords_for_udim.update(tpl)
    return uv_coords_for_udim


def uv_coords_to_udims(uv_coords_for_udim):
    '''Convert UV vertex position to UDIM`s'''
    # Crop by UDIM index range
    croped_uv_coords_for_udim = []
    for i in uv_coords_for_udim:
        if (1 > i[0] or i[0] > 10) or (0 > i[1] or i[1] > 99):
            continue
        else:
            croped_uv_coords_for_udim.append(i)

    udims = []
    for i in croped_uv_coords_for_udim:
        # Converting UV coordinates to UDIMs
        tile_value = i[0]+(i[1]*10)+1000
        udims.append(tile_value)
    udims.sort()     
    return udims
    

def split_udims_by_group(lst):
    result = []
    sublist = [lst[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[i] - lst[i-1]==1:
            sublist.append(lst[i])
        else:
            result.append(sublist)
            sublist = [lst[i]]
    result.append(sublist)
    return result


class IMAGE_OT_missed_tiles_add(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "image.missed_tile_add"
    bl_label = "Missed Tiles Add Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}


    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sima = context.space_data
        return (sima and sima.image and sima.image.source == 'TILED')


    def execute(self, context):
        mode = context.mode
        if context.mode != 'OBJECT':
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        
        uv_coords = create_unique_uv_coords()
        if context.mode != mode:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        udims=uv_coords_to_udims(uv_coords)
        if not udims:
            return {'FINISHED'}    
        print(split_udims_by_group(udims))
        groups = split_udims_by_group(udims)

        for group in groups:
            first_elem_in_group = group[0]
            group_size=len(group)
            
            bpy.ops.image.tile_add(
                number=first_elem_in_group, 
                count=group_size, 
                label='', 
                fill=True, 
                color=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 
                generated_type="BLANK", 
                width=1024, height=1024, 
                float=False, 
                alpha=False)
                

        return {'FINISHED'}
    

class IMAGE_PT_missed_tiles_add(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_space_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Image"
    bl_label = "Missed Tiles Add"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sima = context.space_data
        return (sima and sima.image and sima.image.source == 'TILED' and sima.image.size[0] != 0)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.operator("image.missed_tile_add")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(IMAGE_OT_missed_tiles_add)
    bpy.utils.register_class(IMAGE_PT_missed_tiles_add)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(IMAGE_OT_missed_tiles_add)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(IMAGE_PT_missed_tiles_add)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: It will be nice if the script automatically detects if an object has UDIM and creates an image with `Tiled` checked and add tiles to them.

Comment: The script show `[1001, 1011]` for the default cube

Comment: Default uv has no indentation from neighboring islands, and they can be said to crawl into the neighboring areas, this can be fixed, but in reality it makes no sense. The script can certainly be refined, but when there will be time I will do it